# PHP print(fread(...)) Out of memory error

Tags: php, download, out-of-memory, readfile, fread

I am attempting to use the following code to allow downloads from my website:

```
while(!feof($file)) {
    print(fread($file, 1024*8));
    flush();
    if (connection_status()!=0) {
      @fclose($file);
      die();
    }
}
@fclose($file);
```

It has been working great on files under 20MB, but I recently provided a file around 150MB, and quickly found that no more than 80MB was being downloaded.  After much research I found an out of memory error in the last few lines of the incomplete file:

> **Fatal error**:  Out of memory (allocated 82313216) (tried to
>   allocate 81530881 bytes)

It was my understanding that print(fread(...)) was allocating and reading the (1024*8) bytes from the file, dumping them via print, then utilizing the same 8192 bytes to read/dump the next section of file.

Obviously I have something wrong, can anyone help me understand what is really happening here?  And any possible workarounds for the problem?  Thanks!

Update: The error message refers to line 302, which is:

```
while(!feof($file))
```

Also, the browser displays the progress bar appropriately, so I know the file size is being sent correctly.

Comment: Why you don't use `readfile()` (http://php.net/readfile) (As a sidenote: Its usually a bad idea to pass static content through PHP just because its possible). It mentions "Tried to allocate [~80MB]". You are sure, that this is really the code, that causes the error?

Comment: The error message should normally point out the exact line... :-?

Comment: Are you using outbut buffering? That'd still suck up the entire file into memory even through you're trying to output it into small chunks.

Comment: I was under the impression that readfile() was a bad option for larger files, which led me to this function.  Is this not true?  Yes, the error message refers to line 302, which is:   while(!feof($file))

Comment: Problem found!  ob_start() was being called before this code, and wasn't being ended due a bug in one of my if statements.  So output buffering was the culprit, even though I wasn't aware it was still enabled.    MarcB nailed it... how do I award you the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this:

```
    if ($file!=false){
      while(!feof($file)) {
        print(fread($file, 1024*8));
        flush();
        if (connection_status()!=0) {
          @fclose($file);
          die();
        }
      }
      @fclose($file);
    }
```